# Merge multiple lists in Jinja2

Tags: list, jinja2, nested-lists

Is there a way to combine multiple lists in a list in Jinja2 ?

For instance, if I have :

```
[['foo', 'moo'],['py','jinga','template'],['example'],['stack','overflow']]
```

I expect to get :

```
['foo', 'moo','py','jinga','template','example','stack','overflow']
```

*(I don't know the number of lists in the list in advance.)*

I already tried to use `join()` but it doesn't work because I get a string and not a list of strings.

Answer (score 6):

Since Jinja 2.10, you can use [*namespaces*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-globals.namespace) in order to fulfil this requirement.

For example:

```
{%- set list_of_lists = [
    ['foo', 'moo'],
    ['py','jinga','template'],
    ['example'],
    ['stack','overflow']
] -%}

{%- set ns = namespace(flattened_list=[]) -%}
{%- for list in list_of_lists -%}
  {%- set ns.flattened_list = ns.flattened_list + list -%}
{%- endfor -%}

{{ ns.flattened_list }}
```

Which gives the expected list:

```py
['foo', 'moo', 'py', 'jinga', 'template', 'example', 'stack', 'overflow']
```

---

Prior to Jinja 2.10, if you didn't knew upfront the number of sub list, since Jinja won't allow [assignment in loops](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#assignments), what you could do is to [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) back the sub lists via [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map), then, [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it back.

It is not the perfect way, but it does the job.

```
{% set list_of_lists = [
    ['foo', 'moo'],
    ['py','jinga','template'],
    ['example'],
    ['stack','overflow']
] %}
{{ (list_of_lists | map('join','|||') | join('|||')).split('|||') }}
```

---

You can do a concatenation of lists using the `+` operator:

```py
['foo','moo'] + ['py','jinga','template'] + ['example'] + ['stack','overflow']
```

Gives

```py
['foo', 'moo', 'py', 'jinga', 'template', 'example', 'stack', 'overflow']
```

> `+` Adds two objects together. Usually the objects are numbers, but if both are strings or lists, you can concatenate them this way.

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#math*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a long time coming, but I think that there is a good answer that hasn't been brought up yet. Given your list of lists, you should be able to use the `sum` filter on your list. The template would look something like this:

```
{{ [['foo', 'moo'],['py','jinga','template'],['example'],['stack','overflow']] | sum(start=[]) }}
```

And the result is:

```
['foo', 'moo', 'py', 'jinga', 'template', 'example', 'stack', 'overflow']
```

Seems the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a solution for this problem in **ansible**, and used β.εηοιτ.βε's solution first. Then I found another solution using `json_query` and it's [flatten projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections) (`[]`):

```
- name: stackoverflow test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - flatten list of lists using json_query's flatten projection
      vars:
        nested: [["foo", "moo"],["py","jinga","template"],["example"],["stack","overflow"]]
      debug:
        msg: '{{ nested  | json_query("[]") }}'
```

Not sure if the OP had been using ansible, but if someone else like me ends up here, they might find it useful.

Comment: There is also a `flatten` filter in Ansible, which make the requirement trivial: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/flatten_filter.html